# Google Tablet help need power

Tags: charging, power-on

Just purchased this for Christmas, it will not charge or turn on, any suggestions. 
Have tired several different charger

Comment: You mean NEXUS 7 or Nexus 10?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting it to a computer? Have you tried pressing and holding the power button for a couple of seconds [say, 10]?